# AngularJS own directive - bidirectional binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, directive

I'm implementig custom checkbox directive, right now I'm stuck with followink code:

```
.directive( 'customCheckbox', function() {
return {
            require:"ngModel",
    templateUrl: 'checkbox/checkbox.html',
    link: function( scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                scope.$watch(function(){
                    return ngModel.$modelValue;
                }, function(modelValue){
                    ngModel.$render();
                });

                //ui->model
                element.bind("click", function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){//change value, it will be rendered automatically
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(!ngModel.$modelValue);
                    });
                });

                //model -> UI
                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    //value has already changed, set proper classes on elements
                    if (ngModel.$modelValue == true) {
                        element.addClass("active").removeClass('voided')
                                .find('div').addClass("active").removeClass('voided');
                    }else{
                        element.addClass("active").removeClass('voided')
                                .find('div').removeClass("active").addClass('voided');
                    };
                };

    },

} });
```

The problem is, that when I bind my model to checkbox, everything works fine when I change value with my directive, but unfortunatelly changes I make with checkbox are not reflected on my directive, and I can't figure out why.

I was checking solutions with  [AngularUI radioButton](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/buttons.js) and with [this page](http://suhairhassan.com/2013/05/01/getting-started-with-angularjs-directive.htm).

Comment: Can you make a plnkr or jsfiddle?